# What's the meaning of "lonely banter"?

Tags: meaning

I know the word "banter" means "conversation that is funny and not serious" or "friendly conversation in which people make a lot of jokes with, and amusing remarks about, each other" but I don't get the meaning of "lonely banter", so:

> Coud you please tell me what the meaning of "lonely banter" is?

The text is:

> The next morning, the trailer was unloaded. We climbed into the truck,
>   picked up a new load and drove for another two days, watching the white
>   lines disappear hypnotically beneath the hood, which was the color of bone.
>   We had few forms of entertainment, so we made a game of talking....When we tired of this, we’d turn on the CB and listen to the **lonely banter**
>   *of truckers stretched out across the interstate*.“Look out for a green four-wheeler,” a gruff voice said, when we were
>   somewhere between Sacramento and Portland. “Been picnicking in my
>   blind spot for a half hour.”
>   A four-wheeler, Shawn explained, is what big rigs call cars and pickups.
>   Another voice came over the CB to complain about a red Ferrari that was
>   weaving through traffic at 120 miles per hour. “Bastard damned near hit a
>   little blue Chevy,” the deep voice bellowed through the static. “Shit, there’s
>   kids in that Chevy. Anybody up ahead wanna cool this hothead down?” The
>   voice gave its location.

*Educated* by Tara Westover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Truckers often have a "CB" Radio in their truck, which they use to talk to other truckers.  Truckers are lonely, because they have nobody with them in the truck but they can talk (and banter) with other truckers using the CB radio.  So it just means the banter of lonely truckers.

The author has used lonely to describe the banter. This suggests the things that they talk about in some way indicates their loneliness.

Comment: It should be added that banter usually refers to meaningless or nonstop talking.

Comment: Banter can be all kinds of things: Jokes, comments, put-downs. I would not say that banter is meaningless